# What are translation entries?

Tags: apt, updates, software-installation

I was looking to speed up the

```
    sudo apt-get update
```

Then I found this [blog](http://linuxhalwa.blogspot.sg/2012/07/how-to-remove-translation-entries-while.html) which suggests to remove translation entries

What exactly are translation entries? why they exist in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Help documentation and translations of the programs in other languages. So you can download other "translation entries" and set for instance Firefox to german, swedish or italian if you like. However, if you only use one language in all of your programs, then it makes no sense to check for 100 other translation files that you don't need anyway.